# When finding the frequencies of normal modes, can you have a negative frequency?

Tags: calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Do you simply just consider the positive solutions? I tried a google search but didn't find anything quickly. The work I am studying is Lagrangian systems.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot have negative frequencies.  I assume you are studying lagrangian mechanics and using $$
\det(V-\omega^2 T)=0
$$
in order to calculate frequencies, where V and T are potential and kinetic energy matrices.  We can have an angular frequency $\omega=0$, or $\omega >0$, but never $\omega <0$.  Any more questions let me know.

So to answer your question, you take only the positive root when calculating $\omega$.